# Get more of the metadata from the Neurotransmitter study using Allen SDK

Tags: allen-sdk

I am downloading all the images from the Neurotransmitter study of the Allen Brain Atlas using this script:

```py
from allensdk.api.queries.image_download_api import ImageDownloadApi
from allensdk.config.manifest import Manifest
import pandas as pd
import os


#getting transmitter study
#product id from http://api.brain-map.org/api/v2/data/query.json?criteria=model::Product

nt_datasets = image_api.get_section_data_sets_by_product([27])

#an instance of Image Api for downloading
image_api = ImageDownloadApi()


for index, row in df_nt.iterrows(): 
    #get section dataset id
    section_dataset_id= row['id']

    #each section dataset id has multiple image sections    
    section_images = pd.DataFrame( 
        image_api.section_image_query(
        section_data_set_id=section_dataset_id)
    )

    for section_image_id in section_images['id'].tolist():
        file_path = os.path.join('/path/to/save/dir/', 
                                 str(section_image_id) + '.jpg' )
        Manifest.safe_make_parent_dirs(file_path)
        image_api.download_section_image(section_image_id, 
                                         file_path=file_path,
                                         downsample=downsample)
```

This script downloads presumably all the available ISH experiments. However, I am wondering what would be the best way to get more of the metadata as follows:

1) **type of ISH experiment**, known as "gene" (for example whether an image is MBP-stained, Nissl-stained or etc). Shown in red circle below.

[image: image1]

2) Structure and **correspondence to the atlas image** (annotations, for example to see to which part of brain a section belongs to). I think this could be acquired with `tree_search` but not sure how. Shown in red circles below from two different webpages on Allen website.

[image: image2]

3) The **scale** of the image, for example how big one pixel is in the downloaded image (e.g., 0.001x0.001 mm). I would require this for image analysis with respect to MRI, for example. Shown below in the red circle.

[image: image3]

All the above information are somehow available on the website, my question is whether you could help me to do this **programmatically** via the *SDK*.

EDIT:

Also would be great to download "Nissl" stains programmatically, as they do not show using the above loop iteration. The picture is shown below.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access this information, you'll need to formulate a somewhat complex API query.

```py
from allensdk.api.queries.rma_api import RmaApi

api = RmaApi()

data_set_id = 146586401

data = api.model_query('SectionDataSet', 
                       criteria='[id$eq%d]' % data_set_id, 
                       include='section_images,treatments,probes(gene),specimen(structure)')

print("gene symbol: %s" % data[0]['probes'][0]['gene']['acronym'])
print("treatment name: %s" % data[0]['treatments'][0]['name'])
print("specimen location: %s" % data[0]['specimen']['structure']['name'])
print("section xy resolution: %f um" % data[0]['section_images'][0]['resolution'])
```

```
gene symbol: MBP
treatment name: ISH
specimen location: Cingulate Cortex
section xy resolution: 1.008000 um
```

Without doing a deep dive on the API data model, `SectionDataSets` have constituent `SectionImages`, `Treatments`, `Probes`, and source `Specimens`.  `Probes` target `Genes`, and `Specimens` can be associated with a `Structure`.    The query is downloading all of that information for a single `SectionDataSet` into a nested dictionary.

I don't remember how to find the specimen block extent.  I'll update the answer if I find it.

Comment: Thank you. Would be great to know the block extent as well or at least get some guidance where it might be.

Comment: Is there also a way to add Nissl to the collection here? Each dataset id has at least one Nissl which does not appear as any "gene symbol". I have added a picture above to clarify. Thank you.

Comment: Hi @davidf - I have posted a very similar question and wondering if you'd be able to help me out. Thanks! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66252059/download-ish-section-dataset-images-from-allen-institute-brainspan-with-gene-pro